# Distance length and viewing angle

Tags: trigonometry, triangles, angle

I'm developing a game through BabylonJS and there's four values that are of interest. The environment around the person is a sphere. This sphere has radius 100. The person may move forward from the origin to stand closer to the wall of the sphere and they can theoretically change their field of view (in radians) in addition to going closer to the camera. I want to know what is the viewing angle if we were to look at this from the origin.

Each time I try to tackle this with trigonometry that I've learned thus far, I get more unknowns than I want. I would really appreciate any help.

edit: we also know that the person's new distance from the wall of the sphere is 20 times its viewing angle in radians. I.e. if the person is 20units away from the side of the sphere, it's viewing angle is 1Radian.

[image]

Comment: As you define it, as they get close to the wall the viewing angle goes to zero.  At a distance of $1$ the angle is $0.05$ radians.  Is that each side of center or the total of both sides?  If they are at the center the viewing angle is $5$ radians, which is most of the circle if it is the whole angle and more than the whole circle if it is the half angle.  Please check.

Comment: It is the total of both sides. Why would it be most of the circle? The property you mentioned only applies to the person's position, not the center position.

Comment: But if they are in the center, their distance from the circle is $100$.  The whole angle of the circle from the center is $2\pi \approx 6.28$ radians

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the figure below.  The main circle is radius $100$.  The distance from the wall is $h$, which gives the angles $h/40$ and $\pi-h/40$.  Then by the law of cosines we can write 
$$100^2=(100-h)^2+f^2-2(100-h)f\cos(\pi-h/40)$$,
solve that for $f$ and use the law of sines to write
$$\frac f{\sin BAD}=\frac {100}{\sin (\pi-h/40)}$$

[image]